# Any exploitable structure for modular multiplicative inverses

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-fields

In order to speed up some Reed Solomon codecs, I'm investigating parallel algorithms for multiplicative inverses in $GF(929)$ and $GF(113)$. What I've understood as an non-mathematician is that e.g. for $GF(2^8)$ there exists a composite field, in which the multiplicative inverse can be calculated using merely operations on $GF(2^4)$ coupled with affine transformations back and forth the original field and the composite field.

From numerological perspective it seems possible, that the fields used for those particular prime fields are carefully chosen by non-engineers to allow some computation to happen on smaller relative primes, maybe in a residue system -- $929 - 1 = 2^5 * 29$, $113 - 1 = 2^4 * 7$. This begs the question if likewise the $GF(2^{2m})$ cases, the multiplicative inverses in $GF(929)$ and $GF(113)$ could be calculated by most work done on smaller fields.

If not, I'm likely to use parallel modular exponentiation or scalar binary extended gcd.

**EDIT**

As described in the first answer, the points 2 and 5 do help in reducing the lookup table, both by a factor of 2.

$a^{-1} = N-(N-a)^{-1}$ leads to necessity to store only 50% of the coefficients. Furthermore $(2a)^{-1} = 2^{-1}a{-1}$ meaning that one only needs to store the odd table entries at the cost of one (constant) modular multiplication.

This last point may be practically extended to cover multiples of 3, meaning that for every *a* mod 6, one needs to store the values for the remainders 1 and 5, saving 66% of the LUT entries and suffer the cost of some additional calculations.

For the case of $GF(929)$ it might be lucrative to try to compress the table by including multiples of 5 as well, reducing the table of inverses to slightly less than 128.

Comment: The reduction of inverses of $GF(2^8)$ to those of $GF(2^4)$ is more or less totally analogous to the reduction of the calculation of inverses of complex numbers to inverses of reals. As in
$$\frac1{x+iy}=\frac{x-iy}{(x+iy)(x-iy)}=\frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}.$$ In other words, it relies on the fact that $GF(2^8)$ is a 2-dimensional space over $GF(2^4)$ much like $\Bbb{C}$ is a 2-dimensional space over $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: As $929$ and $113$ are primes, a similar structure is not available. Sure, some other speed up may be possible. But, what kind of a device are you implementing this on? These fields are rather small. Is a look-up-table of inverses an option, or can you not spare the memory (or, am I so out of touch with the reality of hardware that looking up from a table is slower than a number of arithmetic steps)?

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, so this is likely useless. But, may be [Montgomery multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_modular_multiplication) could give some ideas?

Comment: I am implementing the RS codec on arm64 architecture with SIMD. The fields are small and I'm merely considering alternatives for look up tables. For e.g. GF 2^8, a parallel algorithm takes ~15 instructions handling 16 inverses in parallel, beating a lookup table. Using AVX-512 same is achievable in 3 instructions. It's possible, that for 113 the best bet is to a LUT of size 64. For 929 the LUT needs to be 2K sized with likely cache misses.

Comment: I have tested optimal Addition Chains, Montgomery Power Ladder with and without  Montgomery Multiplication, and they are even slower than Barrett reduction, especially when one does not need to reduce the full range of int32_t after multiplication, nor reduce perfectly, saving several instructions compared to what gcc/clang generate for `int z(int a) { return a % 929; }`. What I haven't tried is a split up reduction from left and right simultaneously.

Comment: via my point 4 , you can actually use  a version of the modular version of the Euclidean algprithm and inverse only once you get low enough to know it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tons of structure:

1. The multiplicative inverse of the additive inverse, is the additive inverse of the multiplicative inverse.
2. The multiplicative inverse of a number, is the product of multiplicative inverses of it's factors.
3. for composite moduli, the multiplicative inverse of a remainder, is its multiplicative inverse of all the modulus' prime power factors put together with CRT.
4. the additive inverse of the multiplicative inverse of the modulus, modulo the remainder times the modulus, plus 1 will be divisible by the remainder giving the multiplicative inverse.
5. By Euler's totient theorem raising the remainder to the $\phi (n)-1$ exponent, is congruent to the multiplicative inverse.
   $$\vdots$$

just to review a few.

Comment: Thanks. 1 can be used to reduce the size of a look up table by 50%. 2 may be unexploitable (in parallel algorithms, as each input has its own factorisation. 3 and 5 can't be used for prime fields. I need to digest point 4.

Comment: point 4 is an explicit formula ... $a^{-1}=\frac{-(b^{-1})b+1}{a}\pmod b$ where $b^{-1}$ is taken mod $a$ .

Comment: Fermat's little theorem is just a special case  of Euler, so you are wrong on point 5.  If you find a field/group generator  there's  the logic that if $m$ is the generator raised to $n$ then  $m^{-1}$ is just  the max order minus $n$ as the new exponent.

Comment: Yes indeed. 5 is actually the backup method I intend to use in lack of a computationally easier method.

Comment: point 2 can partially be used in that any number with the same radical ( distinct prime factors)  will be some multiplier away, and modular classes have multiple names ...

Comment: a power residue is by rule the multiplicative inverse of  another power residue with same exponent. if it has one.